# What is more efficient searching a table directly or indirectly using a connected table

Tags: graphql, hasura

This is for a personal side project,

I have a table called `users` that is indexed on `id integer, primary key, unique, default: nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)`

and I have another table called `messages` with `senderId` and `receiverId` both connected to foreign key id from the `users` table.

Would it be more efficient to query `users_by_pk` and then show the node `messages` or would it be more efficient to go query `messages` and filter by `senderId` and `receiverId`?

My gut is telling me to query `users_by_pk` due to the fact that `id` is both the primary key and the `id` of the `user`.

Please no sarcastic/better than you replies.

Thanks

Comment: `I have a table called users` - so your question about DB structures exposed with graphql.    You said nothing about how they are registered in hasura. Do you have object/array relationships `users`->`messages` and/or `messages->users` ? Can you show examples of graphql queries you tried? Did you look what Analyze shows?